# How to support multiple unit systems for users in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want to support our users with the ability to **enter measured values** in their **preferred unit system** depending on their locale. For example if they want to enter their weight, users of Germany enter [kg] and users of UK enter [pounds].

Are there any known gems or helpers so support this functionality within forms for active record models. Also it would be nice if the entered value is always converted to a target unit system (e.g. each value is saved in [kg]).

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to store all this information in the database without changing it or converting it.

You should have a table **mapping** the unit systems and countries (or unit systems and users if it is a preference not bound by country).

Considering you have a field "*measured_value*", you should also have a "*unit_system*" in the same table. This way everytime you want to show the value in different unit systems, your just have to look up the mapping table to calculate the new value.

This allows you to keep things separated and stored in a way that will allow you to make changes in the future without ever losing the original values. (this is specially important if  any of the converting values change over time, i.e. *currency*)